# How to open pdf in new windows without download

Tags: html, css, pdf

how to open the pdf in new window?
I try with this but again download instead of open in new window.
This i use:

```
 <a href="../PDF/Allgemeine_Lieferbedingungen_Main.pdf" target="_blank" >downloaden</a></p>
```

how to make it open?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install a pdf reader plugin. If the plugin is not installed the browser will always download the file.

Comment: But even then, it depends on the user's settings; it can not be fully controlled from the server's side.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that is not really clean, but which can work in your case is to use an iframe in a page you create, and send  PDF path as query in your URL to load into your target iframe.

```
<a href="../pdfWindow.html?pdfURL=../PDF/Allgemeine_Lieferbedingungen_Main.pdf" target="_blank" >downloaden</a></p>
```

Then, in your "pdfWindow.html" page, create an iframe, and add JS which may look like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url =  window.location.href;
    var queries = url.split("?");
    var ref = queries[1];
    $("#iframe").prop("src", ref );
});
```

For SEO, you should transform your href with javascript in order to keep your path clean for bots, not sure they like PDF files in queries. To be confirmed. As I said, it is not really clean.